# What are the texts of Vajrāyana Buddhism? And where can I get?

Tags: vajrayana

- What are the scriptures of Vajrāyana Buddhism? Or texts related?
- Where can I get scriptures or texts on Vajrāyana Buddhism?

Comment: See also related question; [*"What are the core Mahayana and Vajrayana Sutras?"*](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/9777/what-are-the-core-mahayana-and-vajrayana-sutras?rq=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This person – **Andrea Pema** will be able to help you on this. If asked just say that Saptha Visuddhi referred you to him.
[**Andrea Pema**](https://www.facebook.com/andrea.pema.1/notes?lst=100007798020285%3A100001666351698%3A1497175009) has translated many of  Vajrāyana Buddhism text to English. The follow are few of his notes:

[The Progressive Stages of Meditation. From Shamata to the Beginning of the Mahasandhi](https://www.facebook.com/notes/andrea-pema/the-progressive-stages-of-meditation-from-shamata-to-the-beginning-of-the-mahasa/1281621138525860/)

[An Excerpt from my Book “Buddha Dharma”: Introduction to the Vajrayana (for Advanced Yogis and Yoginis as well as for Beginners)](https://www.facebook.com/notes/andrea-pema/an-excerpt-from-my-book-buddha-dharma-introduction-to-the-vajrayana-for-advanced/1344880485533258/)

[On the three Buddha Bodies - the Buddhist Sutra and Tantra on the Qualities of Enlightenment](https://www.facebook.com/notes/andrea-pema/on-the-three-buddha-bodies-the-buddhist-sutra-and-tantra-on-the-qualities-of-enl/1008028932551750/)

[The Guru Yoga Practice of Padmasambhava, for Beginners and Advanced Practitioners](https://www.facebook.com/notes/andrea-pema/the-guru-yoga-practice-of-padmasambhava-for-beginners-and-advanced-practitioners/1340957535925553/)

[A short advice on how to do Deity Yoga in Buddhist Tantra](https://www.facebook.com/notes/andrea-pema/a-short-advice-on-how-to-do-deity-yoga-in-buddhist-tantra/1314592428562064/)

[What is “Bodhicitta” in the Tantra ?](https://www.facebook.com/notes/andrea-pema/what-is-bodhicitta-in-the-tantra-/1275616569126317/)

[A Gem of Compassion from the Mahayana; The Practice of Tonglen, a “must” for those that follow the Bodhisattva Path](https://www.facebook.com/notes/andrea-pema/a-gem-of-compassion-from-the-mahayana-the-practice-of-tonglen-a-must-for-those-t/1267394463281861/)

[The Dharani of Lapis Light that generates the Power of the Tathagatas Meditative Absorption](https://www.facebook.com/notes/andrea-pema/the-dharani-of-lapis-light-that-generates-the-power-of-the-tathagatas-meditative/1170829602938348/)

[On Shunyata ( Emptiness)](https://www.facebook.com/notes/andrea-pema/on-shunyata-emptiness/1119328868088422/)

[On meditation and sacred outlook](https://www.facebook.com/notes/andrea-pema/on-meditation-and-sacred-outlook/1010887288932581/)

[The Path of Bliss in Buddhist Tantra](https://www.facebook.com/notes/andrea-pema/the-path-of-bliss-in-buddhist-tantra/207639719257346/)